# What do i call a 'Mutable configuration'

Tags: design, naming

I have an external process in my program. To interact with it i have a configuration file i can edit. The external process then reads this file periodically and updates its state accordingly.

Now what is a good name for this file, as represented in code?

`ExternalProcessApplicationConfigurationFile` feels 'static' since using configuration as a word 'sounds static' as in the configuration is not mutable. Although i feel something like 'ExternalProcessApplicationSettingsFile' sounds even more static.

How would you normally call something like this situation, where an external module in your code has a configuration that is mutable.

Comment: `Config`, and add to its documentation that it's mutable and that the program will check every N minutes for changes. A name doesn't need to convey everything about its functionality and intended usage.

Comment: Alternatively, call it a parameters file.

Comment: @Hans-Martin Mosner your comment should be an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Config`, or maybe `Configuration` or `Settings`. A name doesn't need to convey everything about its functionality and intended usage.

The documentation should state that it's mutable and that the program will check every N minutes for changes (or utilizes a file modification monitor.)